# Android: Image doesn't load on device while it does on emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-view

I'm making an app where user can load an image, edit and save it. 
Currently, I made the app so that the background of the view is set to a default image which is quite big (1.4mb). I located the image in drawable folders (all three of them).

When I run this app on emulator (heap and ram size increased), it works well but the log shows there's error opening trace file(2). However, I searched online regarding this problem, and it seemed pretty irrelevant with the issue I was having.

If I run this app on a device (I manually copy-pasted .apk file from bin folder to the device), the app runs but the background is just white without the default image.

Can anyone help me finding the issue?

Thank you so much.

Comment: "I manually copy-pasted .apk file from bin folder to the device" why not compile to device and sign it and install it, as it should be done? - or via usb cable deploy

Comment: Have you tried connect the phone to your computer and listen for error message?

Comment: the device I'm using is a touch screen monitor that has android os built in it. I had issues with detecting the device when running it on eclipse and the company explained that I can run it in that way.

Comment: I tried running it on my phone as well and it works without any error. It seems like I can't load the background image only when it is ran on that monitor. Can anyone think of any reason this might happen?

Answer (score 0):

Is your app using a layout or resolution folder-customization that is made for a different form-factor (screen size|resolution)?

Also, are your views|container aligned & sized properly, or relative to something that moved or moved off-screen on the bigger monitor?

Without more specific details, it's hard to help.